# Boost MPL to generate code for object serialization?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I want to generate serialization/deserialization code for

```
class Object
{
    string a;
    int b;
    long c;
    char d;
};
```

by looking at a mpl sequence, but I need to be able to identify object and retrieve it back as well, I can't figure out how would I get the names of it members, **do I have to know it**?

code should look like

```
void SerializeObject(ostream os)
{
   serialize(object.a, os);
   serialize(object.b, os);

   //serialize(object.member, os);
}
```

I want to generate above code by user only defining a mpl sequence corresponding the object layout, is it doable, can you give me some hints?

my aim is:

User defines `mpl::vector<String, int, long, char>` for above object and my `metaprogram` can generate the coded needed.

Comment: I don't think you can get the names of your members without some serious hacking. Consider what happens if you have two ints for instance. How would boost::mpl know which int is which?

Comment: @Boaz, I don't care as long as I get both the `int`s in the same sequence I passed them in.

Answer (score 10):

Consider a `boost::fusion`, and use the macro `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT()` to promote your structure to a fusion sequence (random access), e.g. once you've defined the above structure, you can do something like

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Object,
    (std::string, a)
    (int, b)
    (long, c)
    (char, d)
)
```

Now that it's been promoted, you can simply use a `for_each` to iterate over the members, something like:

```
template<typename archive>
struct serializer {
   serializer(archive& ar):ar(ar) {}

   template<typename T>
   void operator()(const T& o) const {
      ar & o;  // assuming binary for example...
   }
   archive& ar;
};

template<typename archive, typename sequence>
void serialize(archive& ar, sequence const& v) {
   boost::fusion::for_each(v, serializer<archive>(ar));
}
```

To use, it should be as simple as:

```
Object foo; // instance to serialize
serialize(<archive>, foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no ways to infer member names in templates.  You'll need to specify everything explicitly, like this:

```
template<typename ObjT, typename MemberT, MemberT ObjT::*Ptr>
struct member{};

mpl::vector
<
    member<Object, string, &Object::a>,
    member<Object, int, &Object::b>,
    member<Object, long, &Object::c>,
    member<Object, char, &Object::d>
>;
```

Another option is to create functions to help generate `member`, define an `operator>>` for `member` that merges them into a `member_vec`, and an `operator>>` for `member_vec` that merges into a larger `member_vec`.  Since you're only using the type, the compiler can optimize away any actual function calls

Functions can use implicit template arguments, so it can make serializers take a bit less code to define:

```
auto serializer =
        mem(&Object::a) >>
        mem(&Object::b) >>
        mem(&Object::c) >>
        mem(&Object::d);
```

I've made serializers myself, using both techniques.  The second one is what I'm most happy with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mpl::string` to represent member names.  In my app, I do a little bit of code generation that emits something like the following.

```
typedef mpl::string < 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e' > name;
```

You can use the `mpl::c_str < name >::value` to get the string representation. i.e. "name".

I store a sequence of such member names, another sequence for member pointers, zip them together and then use one of the boost::fusion query algorithms to find the member pointer for a given member name.

I'll post code if you are interested. Currently I don't have access to it since it is in my home PC.